# Calculate the volume of the part of a sphere that is submerged in the water

Tags: calculus

I am looking to find the volume of the part of a sphere which is submerged below the water with the following information given:

- the solid sphere has diameter 10cm
- the top of the sphere is 2cm above the surface of the water.

I am stuck for ways to start this problem.. anyone have a few hints they could share with me?

Comment: This question has been asked at least three times today.

Answer (score 3):

It's a one-liner in calculus using the disk method:

$$
V=\pi\int_{-3}^{5}\left(\sqrt{5^2-x^2}\right)^2\,dx=
\pi\int_{-3}^{5}(25-x^2)\,dx
$$

Comment: Thank you for your help!